# Wake a deferred task object without invoking future<T>.get()

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, stdasync, std-future

What happens when you call std::future::wait_for on a deferred task object?

Ideally I would like to wake a deferred task but not take the hit of processing the task in the current thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `async` with the `launch::deferred` policy will not execute the deferred task until the first call to a non-timed waiting function (one that blocks like `get`).  This is spelled out in the language spec, [futures.async] section, paragraph 3.2:

> The first call to a non-timed waiting function (33.6.5)
>   on an asynchronous return object referring to this shared state shall invoke the deferred function
>   in the thread that called the waiting function.

So this will run the task in the current thread.  I suppose you could create another thread, and pass it the task to run.